# How to write a spring-boot application integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring-boot application with several `@RestController`s. Now I want to write an `@IntegrationTest` to test my application.

I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:0")
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Test public void someTest() {}
}
```

this code works fine.

I have splitted my tests in several test classes. One test class per `@RestController` e.g. `TestClass1` and `TestClass2`.

My question is how do I include those test classes? I am looking for something like the JUnit Suite tests:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class) and @SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, ...})
```

I cannot add another `@RunWith` to my `ApplicationTests` class and if I add all these annotations

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port:0")
```

to each of my test classes it causes to start the Tomcat once per test class and this is what I want to avoid. So basically start the Tomcat once and run all tests which are splitted into several test classes.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using @DirtiesContext annotation?

Comment: No I am not. And this is also not what I want. @DirtiesContext provides new context for each test method/class. I want to run several test classes: TestClass1 and TestClass2 with booting tomcat only once.